# How to design the system used for data query and data update

Tags: php, proxy, system, thrift

The target is simple： clients post http requests to query data and update record by some keys。 Highest request: 500/sec (the higher the better, but the best is to fulfil this requirement while making the system easy to achieve and using less mashines)

what I've done: nginx + php-cgi(using php) to serve http request, the php use thrift RPC to retrieve data from a DB proxy which is only used to query and update DB(mysql). The DB proxy uses mysql connection pool and thrift's TNonblockingServer. (In my country, there are 2 ISP, DB Proxy will be deployed in multi-isp machine and so is the db, web servers can be deployed on single-isp mashine according to the experience)

what trouble me: when I do stress test(when >500/sec), I found " TSocket: Could not connect to 172.19.122.32:9090 (Connection refused [111]" from php log. I think it may be caused by the port's running out(may be incorrect conclusion). So I design to use thrift connection bool to reduce thrift connection. But there is no connection pool in php (there seem to be  some DB connection pool tech) and php does not support the feature.

So I think maybe the project is designed in the wrong way from the beginning(like use php ,thrift).  Is there a good way to solve this based on what i've done? And I think most people will doubt my awkward scheme. Well, your new scheme will help a lot

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"TSocket: Could not connect to 172.19.122.32:9090 (Connection refused [111])" from php log shows the ports running out because of too many short connections in a short time. So I config  the tcp TIME_WAIT status to recycle port in time using:
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=1 
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1

it works! 
what droubles me is sloved, but to change the kernal parameter will affect the NAT. It's not a perfect solution. I think a new good design of this system can be continue to discuss.